# can we specific Ksql table start time

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, ksqldb

I have a requirement to create window that start at 5 am and last for 24 hours
I can not find a way to specify window start time , only how to define window size
if I defined it as 24 it automatically start at 12 am
any help?

Answer (score 1):

ksqlDB windows start at the UNIX epoch (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970) and this cannot be changed.

Comment: Thanks Robin fore replying , so I have to make all event logic to start at 12 am , there is no work around in this issue?

Comment: The only workaround would be to "shift" your input data timestamps accordingly.